# jquery slider logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slider

I know there are tons of sliders out there and what I want to do is something like Coda-Slider, however I want to learn JavaScript (jQuery) and work with what I have instead of changing all the HTML code to an existing slider's required syntax.

One of my biggest problems is that I think too complicated about simple things and expect complicated stuff to be solved easily.

[sketch](http://typo3.p136109.mittwaldserver.info/fileadmin/images/slider.png)

```
var shopContent = $('div.tx-jfmulticontent-pi1');
var shopTrigger = $('div.shop-items > div');

for(var i=0; i < shopTrigger.length; i++) {
    $(shopTrigger[i]).click(function(){
        $(shopContent[i]).slideUp();                              
    });
}
```

My idea was: use the clicked item's (trigger div) index number to animate the content div with the corresponding index. Obviously, when I check i's value with console.log, I get 12 (number of trigger items) since the for loop runs quickly through!

I would appreciate a lot if you can give me some directions where I should start learning how to solve these kind of problems. Not sure, maybe I have to go back to the very basics of JavaScript but most of the time, I can draw a scheme what kind of events and actions are needed but I totally suck at turning it into code.

Thanks for any kind of help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/odeta3/2

this is a very spartan demo but you can get the idea

you can easily do this by using

```
<div id="container">
<div id="display-image"></div>
<ul id="display-thumbs">
<li><img /></li><li><img /></li><li><img /></li><li><img /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {  
  $('#display-thumbs li img:first').clone(true).appendTo('#display-image');  
    $('#display-thumbs li img').click(function() {
        var image = this.src;
        $('#display-image img').animate({
            'top': '-425px'
        },
        500,function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('<img></img>').attr('src', image).css('top', '425px').appendTo('#display-image').animate({
                'top': '0'
            },
            500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the idea. Hopefully I can learn to think this way by practicing more.